# Iot Central to Blob Storage Data encrypted telemetry data body

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

i have got a problem regarding saving telemetry data/json into a blob storage. 
The problem is that the saved data has sort of encrypted my valuable telemetry data.

```
{"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2019-11-25T15:42:51.5340000Z","Properties":{},"SystemProperties":{"to":"/devices/device-08/messages/events","connectionDeviceId":"device-08","connectionAuthMethod":"{\"scope\":\"device\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","contentEncoding":"","enqueuedTime":"2019-11-25T15:42:51.5340000Z"},"Body":"eyJ0ZW1wIjo3LjM5LCJodW0iOjczLjUsInJzc2kiOi04OSwic25yIjo4Ljh9"}
```

I think the problem also lays within "contentEncoding":"" cause it should be"contentEncoding":"utf-8".

Does anyone know how to fix this :) thank you very much for your efforts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#azure-storage) document.

Set the device message system properties such as the *contentType* to **application/json** and *contentEncoding* to **UTF-8**.

In the case when your device is using the MQTT protocol directly, use the topic for passing the system properties, for example:

```
 devices/mydeviceId/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

**Update:**

The following screen snippets are showing an example of the quick test for Data export to the blob storage.

1. Creating a IOT Central Application with a PnP device template (environmentalSensor) assigned to the device1 and Data Export to the blob storage:

[image]

2. Using an Azure IoT Hub Tester for simulation of the PnP device1 connected to the IoT Central directly via MQTT protocol:

[image]

As you can see, the published topic is

```
devices/device1/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

and 6 messages have been sent to the IoT Central.

3. Showing a telemetry data on the IoT Central dashboard.

[image]

4. Using the Azure Storage Explorer for exploring a blob content:

[image]

As you can see, the body of each device message is not Base64 encoded json text.

**Note, that only *contentType* and *contentEncoding* of the device message will decide if the body is Base64 encoded or not.**

Comment: Thank you for answering. The device troubling me isn't one I set up myself. My device didn't encounter this Problem. 
I don't know where to change the parameters. Is this the devices problem or an Azure service?

Comment: See my update. Are you sure, that your device sent a telemetry message with a system properties *contentType=application/json* and *contentEncoding=utf-8* ?